# Not able to update from html page to database

Tags: php, html, database

i have made a table which includes 4 columns as Name,LName,DOB,ID ... When i update Name , LName , DOB its working but when i try to update the ID its not been updated.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test", $con);

    if(isset($_POST['update'])){
            $myID= $_POST['IDe'];
            $myname11 = $_POST['namee'];
            $mysurname11 =$_POST['surnamee'];
            $mydob11 = $_POST['DOBe'];

            //updating database from your table
            $sql="UPDATE direct set Name='$myname11',LName='$mysurname11',DOB='$mydob11',ID='$myID' 
            where ID='".$myID."'";
            mysql_query($sql) or die('Error');
            header("Location: viewdata.php");
        }
        ?>
```

Comment: Id may be primary key and you might be updating it to some existing value. That might be the error.

Comment: Generally, we do not updated Id field of the table.

Comment: Why do you need to update the id?? And you are updating the `id` with the same value??

Comment: chechk if database field ID is autoincrement. If so you cannot update.

Comment: @ProgrammingStudent yes ID is a primary key in my database... but in my assignment i have to change all the values that are present in my database. I m not updating it with the same values

Comment: @Kaushik it is not autoIncrement it is only a primary key.

Comment: is there any error occured? Try to print the SQL and run it directly on your database. is the result same?

Comment: @bhoo-day no error is occured but the ID is not changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> we can't update ID field of table because it's primary key..we can use
>   this primary key(ID) as reference to update it's corresponding
>   records.

Comment: How do you know ? ID is primary key?

Comment: generally in database if table has a column called ID then it's primary key of the table

Comment: Never its depends upon user what type they select for ID.

Comment: @JivaniJaydeep so is there any other way i can edit the ID field

Comment: here is a good solution read it [link](https://support.office.com/client/adding-or-changing-a-tables-primary-key-0dde1a80-d913-4d9b-a1b3-061f24ccd991#__toc327942257)

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
UPDATE direct set Name='$myname11',LName='$mysurname11',ID='$myID' where DOB='$mydob11'
```

Comment: yeah bro this will work but i have to select the row on basis of id and there will be many entries with the same DOB.. is there any other way to select the id and make changes to all the other entities in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Remember, always use proper string concatenation.

```
$sql="UPDATE direct set Name='".$myname11."',LName='".$mysurname11."',DOB='".$mydob11."',ID='".$myID."' where DOB='".$mydob11."'";
```

Comment: u can't use DOB as reference to update values of column because if 2 row has same DOB(it's possible) than two row updated with your query at a time..